# Paypal Single Payout Integration with codeignetor

Tags: php, paypal, payout

I want to do single payout for my users. i have tried sandbox for both sdk and curl . i am getting batch header response with status as pending. I have checked in both accounts , it showing transactions as completed.but i am getting following response.

```
stdClass Object
(
    [batch_header] => stdClass Object
        (
            [payout_batch_id] => MFAW63MEMBDB8
            **[batch_status] => PENDING**
            [sender_batch_header] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [email_subject] => SDK payouts test txn
                )

        )

    [links] => Array
        (
            [0] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [href] => https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/payments/payouts/MFAW63MEMBDB8
                    [rel] => self
                    [method] => GET
                    [encType] => application/json
                )

        )

)
```

Answer (score 0):

Payouts run in a batch, which starts out as pending. You can query the status of the batch later, or register a webhook event listener for some related events:

https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api-basics/notifications/webhooks/event-names/#batch-payouts